# Tweepy OAuth - HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter, tweepy

I'm using the [Tweepy library](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) to implement 'Signin with Twitter' on my website.

As shown in the [Tweepy examples](https://github.com/tweepy/examples/blob/master/appengine/oauth_example/handlers.py), I'm doing:

```
def get(self):

    callback_url = "http://127.0.1.1:8080/social_login/complete/"

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
                                config.twitter_consumer_key, 
                                config.twitter_consumer_secret, 
                                callback_url
                                )

    try:
        redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
    except tweepy.TweepError, e:
        self.redirect_to('error', {'message': e})

    request_token = models.OAuthToken(
            token_key = auth.request_token.key,
            token_secret = auth.request_token.secret
    )
    request_token.put()
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

`File "/home/jeremy/Dropbox/Projects/bibliogram/controllers/handlers.py", line 72, in get
    token_key = auth.request_token.key,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'`

The tweepy.TweepError, e is: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

I tried with the consumer keys and secrets from two different accounts. I don't really understand why it's not working...

Does anyone has any idea? Thanks

Comment: take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/3737378

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning in the `except` handler, so the code proceeds to try and create the request token before it redirects. Put a return there, so it will only proceed if there is no error.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the return. That explains my AttributeError. But do you know why I get this HTTP Error 404: Not Found error?